# Run a function for every groupby df and use the value that the function generates (no df return)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a more or less simple question since my current solution is bothering me.
Please note that the Code provided is only an easy example and I don't really need the length of the group but want to do some other stuff within it in the future.

So my current code looks like this:

```
mylist = []

def get_length(group):
    #do stuff with group e.g. return len
    geoRoutes.append(len(group))

df_.groupby(["A","B","C","D"]).apply(get_count)
```

What I want do have is something like this:

```
def get_length(group):
    #do stuff with group e.g. return len
    return len(group)

myList = []

myList.append(df_.groupby(["A","B","C","D"]).apply(get_count))
```

So in other words I was wondering if there is a similar function such as apply which will not try to change the data frame but literally just run a function for every row/subset of the frame.

Comment: I believe, `.apply` with `inplace=False` set (which is the default) does not change the dataset and returns a new one. So `apply` does exactly what you want.

Comment: yes, but it thought there could be a solution where no dataset in returned at all. So just an apply function where I can use the return value: in this case the length of the group in an separated list that isn't concerned about the original data frame at all

Comment: So `df_.groupby(["A","B","C","D"]).apply(get_count)` doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to perform a normal groupby and then to use `tolist`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 1, 2], "b": [1, 1, 1]})
df.groupby("a").apply(len).tolist()

Out[1]: [2, 1]
```